# Hardness ratio of gamma-ray busrts

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, astrophysics, astronomy, gamma-rays

As we know there are two types of GRB (gamma-ray bursts) classes based on their time duration (t90). The presence of bimodality in histograms also verifies it. Also, I have read many papers in which they classified the two classes, using hardness ratio vs. t90/t50 plane. I just want to ask simply: "what is hardness ratio and how can someone calculate the values of the hardness ratio?"  Please reply if you have a partial answer as well.

Comment: Welcome to SE. The points of this site is to gather questions and their answers. So suggesting that answers could bypass the site with emails is really not what Stack Exchange is about...

Answer (score 2):

"Hardness ratio" is the ratio of the photon counts in two different photon energy bands. It lacks a precise definition. It is dependent on instrumental characteristics and data reduction procedures. It is meaningful for data taken with a particular instrument and reduced in a consistent way.